# Любовь Бога / Божья / Божия

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, выражения

1. What's the difference in grammar, meaning and so forth between

   - `Любовь Бога`
   - `Любовь Божья`
   - `Любовь Божия`
2. There is no such thing like `божественная любовь`, right?

Comment: "Божественная любовь — одно из основополагающих и важнейших понятий христианства." - [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C_(%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's difference, but it's minor, slight stylistic peculiarities.

1. `Любовь Бога` - Like every attribute expressed by the Genitive case it has 2 meanings, the active and the passive one, the former is "I love God", the latter is "God loves me."
2. `Любовь Божья` - This one means "The Love of God, the love of the kind as God loves"
3. `Любовь Божия` - This one is almost the same as #2, but it's more Church-Slavonic than Russian, it sounds the way they say it in churches.
4. `Божественная любовь` - this is rather different from the previous ones, it means "divine love" which is more about the quality of love than about the subject of love, it's not about who, but about how one  loves.

Comment: Любовь Бога never means "I love God". -1.

Comment: @Anixx - You're wrong. Although that meaning is in most cases expressed by "любовь к Богу", by its very grammatical meaning `любовь Бога` _can_ mean "the love I have to God", just like "your photo" can mean both "the photo you made" and "the photo where you are depicted".

Comment: this is totally wrong.

Comment: @Anixx it is correct in theory. It is just much rarelier used in Russian.

Comment: @Viridianus it is never used this way.

Comment: @Anixx it is, for example, "страх волка" can refer to both situations: "Wolf is frightened" and "Wolf frightens"

Comment: @Viridianus this is different situation, you cannot say "страх к волку".

Comment: @Anixx there is used preposition "перед" - "страх перед волком"

Answer (score 0):

Любовь Божия == Любовь Божья, but first one is old style, second one is new style.
can be an answer for question "What makes you happy?"

Любовь Бога - can be answer for question "Whose love makes you happy?"

Божественная любовь - there is such thing, but usually this phrase does not have anything in common with God. Here "Божественная" is adjective that means something like "great", "awesome" etc.

For example:
Эта еда была божественна!
This dish was awesome!

Comment: Любовь их была под дланью бога, но прилетел ужас на крыльях ночи, все завершилось. )) but *"Эта любовь была божественна!"* sound odd, really odd(probably because of no context), You can say that sex был божественен, еда был божественной. That is not bad hm: [стихъ](http://zadorvadim.blogspot.ru/2013/09/blog-post_25.html). "Божественная любовь" used pretty much in religion related text, as google shows.